# codeigniter acsess data with query

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have an error in my project, can you please help me? Here's my code :

```
$q_cek_login = $this->db->get_where('tbl_karyawan', array('username' => $u, 'password' => $p));
    if(count($q_cek_login->result())>0)
    {
        foreach($q_cek_login->result() as $qck)
        {

            if($qck->id_jabatan==1)
            {
                foreach($q_cek_login->result() as $qad)
                {
                    $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'yesGetMeLogin';
                    $sess_data['username'] = $qad->username;
                    $sess_data['nama_pengguna'] = $qad->nama;
                    $sess_data['id_jabatan'] = $qad->id_jabatan;
                    $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
                }
                //header('location:'.base_url().'pemesanan/pending');
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I get this error :

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$id_jabatan

Filename: models/model_digor.php

Line Number: 26

thx u all..........

Comment: please let we know which line is line 24.

Comment: Is that the right code? I don't see `id_karyawan` (I guess your doing something like `$query->id_karyawan` somewhere)

Comment: oh, i'am sory, it's not id_karyawan but id_jabatan... thx u... can help me ....

Comment: Did you tried `$q_cek_login->num_rows()` instead of `count($q_cek_login->result())` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your dependency class is loaded properly. such as $this->load->library('database'); or $this->load->library('your_built_in_class');

Comment: I've put in autoload, 
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','pagination','form_validation','security');
I try load in class too, but error :
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: database