# take data from database with foreach codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have an error in my project, can you please help me? Here's my code :

```
$q_cek_login = $this->db->get_where('tbl_karyawan', array('username' => $u, 'password' => $p));
if(count($q_cek_login->result())>0)
{
    foreach($q_cek_login->result() as $qck)
    {

        if($qck->id_jabatan==1)
        {
            foreach($q_cek_login->result() as $qad)
            {
                $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'yesGetMeLogin';
                $sess_data['username'] = $qad->username;
                $sess_data['nama_pengguna'] = $qad->nama;
                $sess_data['id_jabatan'] = $qad->id_jabatan;
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            }
            //header('location:'.base_url().'pemesanan/pending');
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get this error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered
```

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$id_jabatan

Filename: models/model_digor.php

Line Number: 26

txu all.............

Comment: Do you have column called `id_jabatan` in your database table?

Comment: yes... i have... id_jabatan foreign key

Comment: point out Line Number: 26 please

Comment: You mean that `id_jabatan` is from another table and not exists in `tbl_karyawan` ?

Comment: line number 26 : if($qck->id_jabatan==1)

Comment: id_jabatan in tbl_karyawan, it a foreign key tbl_karyawan

Comment: possible duplicate of [codeigniter acsess data with query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762534/codeigniter-acsess-data-with-query)

Answer (score 0):

try writing like this-

```
if(isset($qck->id_jabatan) && $qck->id_jabatan==1)
```